# Magento 2: Image Upload Not Calling Validator

Tags: magento2, image, magento-2.1, validation, form-validation

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0. I would like to validate that uploaded image should not exceed 5MB.

**app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Posts\Post.php**

```
public function execute() {
    $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'picture1']);
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    $uploader->addValidateCallback('picture1', $uploader, 'validateUploadFile');
}

public function validateUploadFile($filePath) {
    echo "here";
    exit;
}
```

It's not calling `validateUploadFile` function within that file.

Answer (score 1):

It is because **the second parameter of `addValidateCallback` is the callback object.**

In your case you specified the `$uploader` object but the `validateUploadFile` is defined in the current class.

So you need to call the following instead:

```
$uploader->addValidateCallback('picture1', $this, 'validateUploadFile');
```

Comment: Strange. Still not working :(

Comment: @MikeSmith try to change the content of your `validateUploadFile` method with an exception thrown like `throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Error'));`

Comment: I have done  {public function validateUploadFile($filePath) {   try {           
      } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();exit;                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
       }} Still it's not going in to that function. I have also tried by changing name of function
    }

Comment: @MikeSmith try to do this instead: `public function validateUploadFile($filePath) { throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Error'))‌​; }` just to see if you're function is getting called

Comment: I tried  public function validateUploadFile($filePath) {
        throw new \Exception('Errors');
    } But still it's not calling this function

Comment: @MikeSmith did you try to remove var/cache , var/generation

Comment: OMG. Still not working

Comment: @MikeSmith well I'm out of ideas sorry but that's definitely the way it works as you can see from a core file here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/File.php#L96

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me check & try to solve. If get solved will get back to you with root cause. Thanks again